# QueryDsl with Predicate for two Entities with same name variable

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, predicate

I have two entities in Spring Boot, Entity Child and Parent and both have variable with name firstName and using QueryDsl with predicate like this

```
  @GetMapping("/search")
  public List<Person> getPerson(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Child.class) Predicate predicateChild,
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Parent.class) Predicate predicateParent) {
     return personService.getPerson(predicateChild, predicateParent);
  }
```

Now I want to search by firstName of child and parent by using **aliases** for firstName variable like **childName** and **parentName** instead of firstName - like this:

```
/person/seearch?childName=John&parentName=George
```

If I search like this

```
/person/seearch?firstName=John
```

the query is

```
...where child.firstName = 'John' and parent.firstName = 'John'
```

How can I change parameter name depending on what class they belong?